# google app engine retrieving null values from memcache

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to use the memcache in google app engine and i implemented like this :

```
public static UserDictionary userDictionary = null;
private MemcacheService syncCache;
public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserDictionary.class.getName());

@SuppressWarnings(value = { "unchecked" })
private UserDictionary() {      
    syncCache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
    syncCache.setErrorHandler(ErrorHandlers.getConsistentLogAndContinue(Level.INFO));
}

public static UserDictionary getInstance() {
    if(userDictionary == null) {                
                userDictionary = new UserDictionary();
    }
    return userDictionary;
}


public Entity getFromCache(String userId) {     
        return (Entity) syncCache.get(userId);      
}

public void putInCache(String userId, Entity userEntity) {
    syncCache.put(userId, userEntity,Expiration.byDeltaSeconds(999999999), MemcacheService.SetPolicy.SET_ALWAYS);
}

public boolean isCacheEmpty() {
    long itemCount = syncCache.getStatistics().getItemCount();
    return itemCount == 0L;     
}
```

The problem is that after i put an Object in cache and then i try to get it, the get method return null. I looked in my google app engine and it shows that is an object in memcache.The key is a java String. Both key and value implements Serializable.

Hit count:  0
Miss count: 31522
Hit ratio:  0%
Item count: 15 item(s)

Comment: Are you trying immediately after doing the put? Are you always checking the key of the most recently put value? What happens if you try fetching again after, say, 1 second?

Comment: I tried to retrieve the value after 1 minute and i tried both with older and new value

Comment: Can you share the code where you are actually doing the put and get (calling `putInCache` and `getFromCache`)?