# Memcache Outputting Null Value

Tags: python, memcached

I am trying to implement the pseudocode from the Google documentation, [Memcache Examples](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/memcache/examples), so that I can pass it to a dictionary but I am getting a `null` value. I've researched for solutions, for example, [Google App Engine retrieving null values from memcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321956/google-app-engine-retrieving-null-values-from-memcache), but they were unhelpful.

*How can I get the output of `the_id` cached for 500 seconds and returned for use by the `update_dict` function? What am I doing wrong?*

**CODE:**

```
def return_id(self):
    the_id = str(uuid.uuid1())

    data = memcache.get(the_id)
    print data

    if data is not None:
        return data
    else:
        memcache.add(the_id, the_id, 500)

    return data

def update_dict(self):
    ....
    id = self.return_id()
    info = {
        'id': id,
        'time': time
    }

    info_dump = json.dumps(info)
    return info_dump
```

**OUTPUT:**

> {"id": null, "time": "1506437063"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. The issues were:

1. my key didn't have a proper string name `'the_id'`
2. I wasn't passing data in my else statement

**Solution:**

```
....
the_id = str(uuid.uuid1())

data = memcache.get('the_id') #fix: pass a string for the key name
print data

if data is not None:
    return data
else:
    data = the_id #fix: added the object that needed to be passed to data
    memcache.add('the_id', the_id, 500)
return data
....
```

**OUTPUT:**

> {"id": "25d853ee-a47d-11e7-8700-69aedf15b2da", "time": "1506437063"}
>
> {"id": "25d853ee-a47d-11e7-8700-69aedf15b2da", "time": "1506437063"}